# Swift based server: get files

Tags: ios, file, swift, server, alamofire

I want to transmit files from app to server. I used Alamofire framework to upload files. And the server I used is a swift based server called Swifter. I don't know how to get files transmitted from clients at the server-side. Is there any swift function that used to get these files?

Comment: Your question is too difficult to understand because it isn't clear what your problem exactly is and what you're trying to do. If you could rework you question, it would be much easier to help. Did you successfully upload files to a server using Alamofire and now you don't know how to download them from the server to the client using Alamofire?

Comment: Actually, it is that I don't quite understand how the server work, so I had no idea where to find data that I had uploaded. But I have solved the problem now. I find them in request.body, then save them in a file. Thanks anyway:).

Comment: Cool...glad you got things figured out!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is that I don't quite understand how the server work, so I had no idea where to find data that I had uploaded. But I have solved the problem now. I find them in request.body, then save them in a file.